# Need raix:push working example

Tags: meteor, push-notification

I'm trying to use [raix:push](https://github.com/raix/push) Meteor package but it doesn't work steadily for me. I have a lot of questions and instead of asking them all I just want to look at some working example which would work at least on Android.

Comment: Did you try the basic example in the docs? https://github.com/raix/push/blob/master/docs/BASIC.md

Comment: Yes, I tried it (in combination with default meteor app), and it worked from time to time. But I just tested it again and it works as expected. Thank you!